# Whats a good way to do sentiment analysis on discussions?

Tags: discussion-board, data

Is there a good toolset or even API that I can use to analyze my SharePoint Online discussions and be able to identify trends in sentiment or even top 5 most talked about things etc?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `Not available to SharePoint Online customers`

Reference - [Office 365 Search](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sharepoint-online-search-service-description.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> Developers can call out to an external content enrichment web service
>   to change the managed properties of crawled items before they are
>   indexed. The ability to change managed properties for items during
>   content processing is helpful for tasks such as data cleansing, entity
>   extraction, classification, and tagging.

But in this Ignite video [Search Extensibility in SharePoint 2013](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK4124), the speakers discuss an approach to extensibility in Office 365 using PowerShell

Also to get an idea about how to go ahead with this, if you had SP 2013 OnPrem environment , you can refer the below links.

[How to: Use the Content Enrichment web service callout for SharePoint Server 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163982.aspx)

[Advanced Content Enrichment in SharePoint 2013 Search](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/richard_dizeregas_blog/2013/06/19/advanced-content-enrichment-in-sharepoint-2013-search/)

Basically what it says is that, the CEWS(Content enrichment web service) callout can be used for numerous data cleansing, entity extraction, classification, and tagging scenarios such as performing sentiment analysis on social activity and augment activity with a sentiment score.

Also, if you are game to use outside tools, you can try out the `Google Cloud Platform's Natural Language API` or `Azure Machine Learning's Text Analytics API`. Basically, you can feed them JSON data from the Discussion board and then let them analyze the raw feed to provide you the sentiment analysis.

[Google Cloud Natural Language API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/)

[Microsoft Cognitive Services](https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/documentation)

[Text Analytics API Demo](https://text-analytics-demo.azurewebsites.net/)